# How do I include my company's global styles CDN (for dev use) using Webpack, within a Vue cli project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js, cdn

I've tried importing via the entry file (**main.js**)...

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App'
import router from '@/router/router'
import store from '@/store/store'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import { Popover } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/directives'
import 'https://mycompany/main.min.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(Popover)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

I've tried to find a place within **webpack.base.config** (*externals* or *publicPath*) via numerous posts online - but none answered my question enough to make it work...

The css file delivered over the CDN essentially uses (and thus overwrites) Bootstrap classes, so it needs to be injected into the  *after* Bootstrap - can I do this with my current setup? Vue/Webpack.. or do i need a task runner like Gulp? It's not enough to inject the cdn once we've built the project and have dist files.. we need to see the style changes whilst dev's work on the project.
Is there an easier way than either of those 2 methods, and before anyone asks - no.. they won't make it an npm package due to privacy/security.

Comment: That definitely sounds against some kind of coding standard, surely?
Also, I don't think I was clear; so amended my question. We need to see the style changes whilst working on the project in dev mode, not just once built with dist files.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to just include it in your index.html after all other Styles. 
Btw: you can publish private repos on npm.

Comment: Styles get injected when the app builds - so even if i did put it in index.html, it would be first, with the vendor styles included after it (thus won't overwrite various styles).

We're looking into npm private repo's now.. but not sure if they're going to agree to it or not. Here's to hoping! It would aid other versioning throughout other implementations of our code base too!

Comment: Your build App is a index.html file and some css + js + assets. I dont get why including the external css at the end of the head shouldn't work? I assume you are not using inline css ?

Comment: If you mean once built, then that's not what I need :/ I may not have been clear, will amend the question to suit.
I need devs to see their style changes whilst running the project in dev mode, not just have it work upon building the files and just using the cdn in index.html where i want it (that would be WAY easier!)..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is directly handling the template used by `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

First disable `inject` in `build/webpack.prod.conf`:

```
//...
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  //...
  inject: false,
  //...
})
//...
```

And in your `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>
    <% for (file of htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= file %>">
    <% } %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mycompany/main.min.css">
  <% } %>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div id="app"></div>
  <% if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { %>
    <!-- During development there's less of a problem with putting stylesheets in the body -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mycompany/main.min.css">
  <% } else{ %>
    <% for (file of htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
      <script src="<%= file %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <% } %>
  <% } %>
</body>

</html>
```

What this does is inserting the static files manually, so you can choose the order, in production. During development, the link is written in the body tag, as then there isn't much of an issue with keeping standards.

Comment: I read somewhere about putting the style in a component and importing it last, but it's moot since it would require using css `@import`, which is then written before everything else.